# Getting error 'The requested page could not be found' after https is enabled

Tags: 8, .htaccess, ssl

The link to my content is lost

default settings:

`# Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]`

my serversupport suggested:

`#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

both didn't work, when comment out everything. My link to the content is fixed using http.

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> The link to my content is lost

So you enabled HTTPS and you can no longer see your Drupal website? It sounds like you have uploaded your Drupal installation in public_html and are now serving content from the private_html folder.

If you are on a Direct Admin installation you can toggle the `symlink private_html to public_html configuration` That should make sure the correct files are served via HTTPS as well.

### Enabling HTTPS

The rewrite rules that ship with Drupal are intended for mix-mode HTTPS (in which case your site supports both HTTP and HTTPS).

If you want the best security, just redirect everything to HTTPS. See the 3rd bullet point of [Enabling HTTP Secure (HTTPS)](https://www.drupal.org/https-information):

> For best possible security, set up your site to only use HTTPS, and
>   respond to all HTTP requests with a redirect to your HTTPS site.
>   Drupal 7's $conf['https'] can be left at its default value (FALSE) on
>   pure-HTTPS sites. Even then, HTTPS is vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle
>   attacks](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) if the connection starts out as a HTTP connection before being
>   redirected to HTTPS. Use the [HSTS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hsts) or [Security Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit) module, or
>   set the [Strict-Transport-Security header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in your webserver, and add
>   your domain to the browser [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/), to help prevent users
>   from accessing the site without HTTPS.
>
> You may want to redirect all traffic from http://yourdomain.com and
>   http://www.yourdomain.com to https://youdormain.com. You can do that
>   by adding this to your .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com*
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```
>
> Put that below `RewriteEngine on`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the original rules that were shipped with Drupal. To enforce HTTPS, you can do this:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]

  # Force all traffic to HTTPS, except a local instance
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.local$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The addition here is:

```
  # Force all traffic to HTTPS, except a local instance
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.local$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The third `RewriteCond` prevents a redirect for local development sites, which you may or may not want.

This is the basic idea and may also work, in lieu of the previous statement, if `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` is not available on your server:

```
  # Force all traffic to HTTPS, except a local instance
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can [test rewrite rules with this handy tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

I would have suggested Secure Pages because that is sometimes easier for people to configure, but it looks like only a [sandbox port](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/goba/2632462) of it exists.

Anyway, I have used both rules with success - and they should work for you unless something is wrong in your server/dns/ssl setup.

Note that any redirects to https should occur *before* this statement in .htaccess:

```
  # Redirect common PHP files to their new locations.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(install.php) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(rebuild.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core
  RewriteRule ^ %1/core/%2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  # Rewrite install.php during installation to see if mod_rewrite is working
  RewriteRule ^core/install.php core/install.php?rewrite=ok [QSA,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do I have to add the content again?

Comment: Add the content? What does content have to do here? .htaccess is controlling redirect based on HTTPS state here - not related to content.

Comment: Because of the error 'The requested page could not be found' I tought maybe an reupload of the content is needed.